# How to authenticate HTTP post request while sending push notification to FCM server

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

How to authenticate HTTP post request while sending push notification to FCM server for Android? and what are the mandatory things to know while connecting to FCM Server? Is there any third party api for this?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, A Request to server sends by an HTTP User in the form of a request message which includes the following format:

A Request-line:

Zero or more header (General|Request|Entity) fields followed by CRLF

An empty line (i.e., a line with nothing preceding the CRLF) 
indicating the end of the header fields

Optionally a message-body

**Request-Line**

The Request-Line starts with a method token, followed by the Request-URI and the protocol version, and ending with CRLF. The elements are separated by space SP characters.

Request-Line = Method SP Request-URI SP HTTP-Version CRLF

Comment: What is the meaning of  "Authorization Key=Xyzasasdsadasdasdretertr5tgdfgdf" under Headers? is it a way of authenticating request?